# Coccinelle output

Tags: c, coccinelle

I am a beginner in coccinelle and try to run my first example.

Currently I'am following the steps of [this article](http://lwn.net/Articles/315686/)

1. I created the c file
2. I created the coccinelle script
3. I run it using

   ```
   $ spatch -sp_file test.cocci test.c
   ```

In the terminal I got the expected result as mentioned in the article

```
--- test.c
+++ /tmp/cocci-output-17416-b5450d-test.c
@@ -7,7 +7,7 @@ main(int argc, char *argv[])
         char *buf;

         /* allocate memory */
-        buf = alloca(bytes);
+        buf = malloc(bytes);

         return 0;
 }
```

However the c file didn't change as expected.

Can any body tell me where can I get the changes made by the script?

Comment: Aren't the changes in the file `/tmp/cocci-output-17416-b5450d-test.c` ?

Comment: This file doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using

```
spatch --help
```

I got all the option for the command spatch .
So i should use

```
$ spatch -sp_file test.cocci test.c -o /tmp/newtest.c
```

the result of runing the patch is in /tmp/newtest.c

Answer (score 2):

You can use `--in-place` option.

So the following should do what you want.

`$ spatch -sp_file test.cocci test.c --in-place`